# How can you tell if you have to follow a police officer's instructions?

Tags: united-states, police

If a police officer gives me an order, how can I tell whether or not I'm legally obligated to follow that order? If I ask the officer, is he/she required by law to answer truthfully?

If the police get to order citizens to do whatever they want, under whatever circumstances that they want, then go ahead and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You don't know. You can't know. And you can't force the officer to tell you.

Detention Status

As a practical matter, you have no way of knowing if you are compelled to follow an officer's order because you are being detained unless the officer volunteers that information (your detention status) which they are not compelled to disclose and have every incentive not to disclose.

Consider the situation when the officer does not have *reasonable suspicion* do detain you. If the officer instantly informs you that you are "free to go" then you are likely to leave and end the encounter immediately. However, if the officer says nothing, then you might stay and inadvertently say or do something that would give the officer reasonable suspicion to detain you from that point forward. Your behavior during that detention could lead to probable cause, arrest, etc. Every officer knows they have nothing to gain by being quick to tell you you are free to go.

Deceptive Conduct

To compound the issue, police encounters are particularly problematic because police officers have a lawful right to engage in ***deceptive conduct*** during an investigation including but not limited to ***lying***. You, on the other hand, can be prosecuted for lying to the police conducting an investigation. ([See this article for more information](http://www.policechiefmagazine.org/police-officer-truthfulness-and-the-brady-decision/).)

Hobson's Choice

Therefore, all things considered, police encounters present a [***Hobson's Choice***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice). Either comply with every order in an effort to end the encounter quickly. Or try to press the officer to determine whether you are "***being detained***" or "***free to go***." The former course of action voluntarily cedes some of your rights. The latter risks "provoking" the officer into making your encounter more difficult, painful or costly than it otherwise might be.

Never Consent to Searches

That said, you are never under any obligation to consent to a warrantless search of your home or vehicle. Typically, saying, "I do not consent to searches." is usually sufficient if asked. Evidence obtained from warrantless searches is barred from being used at trial unless you waive this right by consenting to the search. [See this question (and answers) if you are concerned about the officer falsely claiming you gave consent if you didn't](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/consent-to-searches-who-wins-my-word-against-yours).

Never Talk to the Police

As a legal matter, talking to the police can never help your case in court. Anything you say to the police that might help your case (i.e., exculpatory) is not admissible as evidence because it's *hearsay*. On the other hand, anything you say to the police can and will be used against you. In fact, ***even if you are completely innocent of all crimes AND you are completely 100% truthful to the police, you can still give the police all they legally need to convict you of a crime simply by talking to them.*** Whereas, without your statement, they would not have had sufficient evidence to convict. [See this Youtube video for more details and examples of how this can and does happen every day.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-7o9xYp7eE)

Practical Matters

The above analysis presents the reader with some practical concerns.

1. You don’t want to risk being harmed by an officer in fear for his safety.
2. You don’t want to be handcuffed and taken to the police station if you can avoid it.

You must obey all unconditional commands of a peace officer. It does no harm to inform the officer that you are willing to comply with all unconditional legal commands and ask him or her if a given command is, in fact, unconditional.

Some attorneys go in the opposite direction from the "never talk to the police" rule and advise that, say in the case of a domestic violence dispute, the best course of action is to answer police questions matter-of-factly, never lie and never admit guilt. That course of behavior can avoid a potential trip to the police station in handcuffs in the back of a police car even if you are never ultimately arrested.

TL;DR: Police encounters are tricky. It's difficult to know what to do. The best course of action is to educate yourself about your rights and the law and apply judgment and common sense to guide your behavior to achieve the best outcome.

*I am not an attorney. I am not your attorney. This answer is not legal advice. Please consult an attorney to obtain proper legal advice.*

Comment: You can check your detention status by asking the officer if you are free to go.

Comment: @viktor: You can always ask. But they don't have to answer. If they lack ***reasonable suspicion*** but want to continue questioning you anyway they will usually avoid answering. In this situation, they can and often do employ diversionary tactics like giving another order. It's a game of wits where the peace officer knows all about the law and is well trained in effective tactics and procedures. In short, the police have to follow the law. But they are not obligated to inform you of all your rights or answer any questions they don't want to.

Comment: Look if the police don't answer, ask them again very loudly, so passerbys can hear, or inform them you will begin to record the conversation with your phone(something you have a first amendment right to do). Ask again in a way you have evidence of you asking. If they don't reply to the question, say that you're exercising your right to remain silent and begin to leave. If they yell stop, a reasonable person would believe they are not free to leave, which is the moment you are legally detained.

Comment: That may not be the case in all jurisdictions. In my state, you are required to get the consent of both parties when recording a conversation, and I can find no reliable evidence that exempts police officers. However, I'm not a legal expert, so my search may have been lacking.

Comment: They can't force you to answer questions, either, with the possible exception of your name and some other basic information.  Beyond that, you can take the Fifth.

Comment: If you ask the Police if you are being detained or are free to go and they refuse to answer. Simply start walking away. It may behoove you record this process in case things escalate.

Comment: @DigitalFire: That approach won't work. It is bad advice because it could make your situation worse. The purpose of detainment is to investigate the alleged crime and acquire *probable cause* necessary to make an arrest. The standard of for detainment is  *reasonable suspicion* (*Reasonable suspicion* is lower than *probable cause*.) If you attempt to leave while you are being detained (even if the detainment has not been announced) then you could hand the officer the *reasonable suspicion* they need to arrest you. Further, you might also be guilty of not cooperating with an investigation.

Comment: If I asked an officer if I was 'free to go' and they didn't answer, I'd probably tell them that if they don't tell me that I'm being detained that I'll assume that I am not and walk away, before I actually walk away.

Doing that is 'probable cause?'

Comment: Also invoke your right to legal council.  Treat all orders the police gives as Lawful.  There is a time and a place where you can argue the merits of if the order was lawful... during your encounter is neither the time nor the place.  You do not have a right to a phone call, but the cops will give it to you anyway because they can spy on your call unless it is to a clergy member or your lawyer (the latter of who you should be calling... It's great that your Pastor is praying to the wee baby Jesus for you, but Jesus' last encounter with the law isn't something to aspire to).

Comment: @Mowzer I cannot conceive of any situation where a person who did not know they were being detained would cause suspicion by trying to leave after asking if it was okay for them to leave. Going on about their business normally is the least suspicious thing a person can do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I agree with you. I'm sorry if I was unclear. But I think you might have misinterpreted what I was attempting to describe. Leaving's not the problem. Not leaving is. Imagine a scenario where the police have no reasonable suspicion to detain you. But, not knowing that fact, and thinking you are actually being detained, you say or do something incriminating and, thereby, actually hand the police the reasonable suspicion they lacked in the first place. [This video gives a lot of good examples of how such encounters can happen.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-7o9xYp7eE)

Comment: @Mowzer Maybe I'm misunderstanding you somehow, but your reply to me above seems to be the exact opposite of your reply to DigitalFire.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes. I believe there is a misunderstanding. Different context. My reply to DigitalFire was addressing a situation where a suspect attempts to leave while being detained. My reply to you was dealing with a situation where a non-suspect leaves when free-to-go.

Comment: @Mowzer DigitalFire was talking about the situation where a person asks the police if they're being detained and the police don't answer them. So am I. If the police detain you without telling you, the least suspicious thing you can do is go on about your business having no reason to think you're being detained.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Apparently, I misunderstood you then. Let's clarify something before continuing. My comment to DigitalFire was regarding unilaterally ending a detention that involved, say, answering some interview questions. Where at one point it was clear to both parties that you, at minimum, *believed* you were being detained. Then, without being told you are free to go, decide to leave after getting no response from the officer after asking him. It sounds like your scenario is a little different. Your scenario sounds like it might be *before* you believe you are being detained? Correct?

Comment: @Mowzer My scenario is that you have no reason to believe that you are being detained but ask to be sure and are not given an answer. You still have no reason to believe that you are being detained. This could be at any time in a police encounter, assuming that you have no reason to believe that you are being detained.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I agree with you. I still believe this is a case of misunderstanding. I think the misunderstanding began with different interpretations of DigitalFire's comment on 9/22/16@17:52. I interpreted that comment to involve leaving *after* being detained. I don't think you are so focused on the key word: "after." I confirmed this after re-reading your earlier comment where you wrote: "If the police detain you without telling you," "Without telling you" is not part of any of my scenarios. In other words, you were at least under the impression you were being detained before leaving.

Answer (score 35):

First, you have to [know your own](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/when-encountering-law-enforcement-questioning) [rights](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/what-do-if-youre-stopped-police-immigration-agents-or-fbi).

There are detailed laws that describe what police can do and how they are supposed to do it.  Unfortunately, **none of their duties include "informing citizens of their legal rights,"** with the sole exception of informing a detainee of his right to a lawyer, and then only if the officer cares about the admissibility of the detainee's statements in court.  The police have the same rights to lie in their official capacity as do all citizens in their personal capacities.  I.e., **unless an officer is giving sworn statements, he can lie without legal repercussion**.

Furthermore, it appears that police give unlawful orders and take unlawful actions with enough frequency that many large departments are engaged in constant legal battles with watchdog and advocacy organizations like the [ACLU](https://www.aclu.org/defending-our-rights).

So, if you are given an unlawful order you have two choices:

1. Resist and hope that the officer chooses not to escalate the situation by, for example, arresting you.
2. Follow it anyway to reduce the risk of an escalating conflict.

If you suffer harm or your rights are wrongfully infringed by a law enforcement officer the best you can hope for is that someone in his chain of command steps in to stop the impropriety.  Otherwise, the reality is that any vindication will come (if at all) at the end of [a long judicial process](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/54/10).

Comment: The question is how do I tell if the order is lawful?  If an officer tells me I need to go across the street to continue filming their violent actions How do I know if I am actually required to follow those instructions?

Comment: @Chad: _That_ is an even more difficult question, especially because police have so many discretionary/perceptual safe harbors.  To the degree that statutes and the guidance of sites like the ACLU don't make strong statements about a _citizen's_ rights, the answer falls into the "consult a lawyer" category.  If one has a a friendly Police Chief or local Prosecutor one might get them to weigh in on a hypothetical situation.

Comment: So then you are saying this question is too broad to be answered?

Comment: @Chad: No, I like the original question, and I think I provided a useful answer.  You are right that the original question might have been intended as a more theoretical question than the one I answered.  In that case most of my answer still applies, but my comment above would also apply.

Comment: @feetwet "consult a lawyer" is actually a bad answer for this kind of question, because you often do not have time to consult a lawyer between the time when the officer gives you the order, and the time in which you would have to comply if it indeed is a lawful order.

Comment: @SamIam: I agree that it's not an especially _helpful_ answer, but I don't know of a _better_ one than I gave in my June 15 comment.

Answer (score 19):

**Police officers do not get to order citizens to do "whatever they want"!**

In traffic stops, police often ask (in a tone that could be construed to sound like a demand) to search your vehicle during a traffic stop. More often than not, people assent even when they have illegal drugs, weapons, and all other manner of illegal things! The police do not have a right to search your car just because they are suspicious.

However, they also don't need a warrant if there is probable cause to legally search your vehicle. Probable cause means the police must have some facts or evidence suggesting a crime is taking place. Some example of PC are (1) an informant/witness told the police they saw you place something illegal in your car; (2) they see something illegal during the stop - like a weapon or a drug baggie - in plain view: (3) you or a passenger makes an admission (it happens more than you think); (4) they smell marijuanna in states where it has not been decriminalized *and* where you do not have a passenger (when you have a  passenger, smell is no longer adequate probable cause in a decriminalized state, as the  passenger could have been smoking/carrying it). If there is no passenger, probable cause may exist if you are exhibiting signs of operating under the influence.

These are only some limited examples. The point is that an officer’s hunch (even reasonable suspicion) without evidence of illegal activity is not sufficient to search your car. Before searching, he must observe something real.

If an officer *asks* to search your car and you have something you do not want found, say NO. Especially if you are not impaired and there is nothing illegal in plain site.  Always. Profiling happens all the time and people get arrested and convicted all the time from the fruits of consented to searches that they would/may not have done, or would/may not have had the right to do in the event they did it regardless, giving you a viable way to limit the state's (or Fed's) evidence. They may call in drug dogs (they do not always hit if this is what you are hiding), they may say "if you are not hiding anything, what do you care" - at which point I would say "I care about my right to not be unreasonably detained and searched", especially for no good reason. Nothing good can come from allowing a search for which no cause exists; even if you are perfectly clean. It just perpetuates the abhorrent behavior.

Moving traffic violations (e.g. speeding, broken tail-light, expired sticker) are not considered probable cause to search.

When it comes to asking you to identify yourself, the standard is lower. They need have only a reasonable suspicion a crime is taking place.

ID laws can be complicated on their face, and even more so as they get interpreted by state law courts. The Supreme Court upheld state laws requiring citizens to reveal their identity when officers have *reasonable suspicion* to believe criminal activity may be taking place. Commonly known as “stop-and-identify” statutes. These laws permit police to arrest criminal suspects who refuse to identify themselves.

As of only a year ago,  24 states had stop-and-identify laws and others were contemplating them. Regardless of your state’s law, you should not be forced to identify yourself without reasonable suspicion to believe you’re involved in illegal activity.

The police need reasonable suspicion to detain. So if you say "I'm doing nothing wrong, am I free to go?", or "are you detaining me?" and the officer says you’re free to go, leave immediately and don’t answer any more questions.

If you’re detained, you pretty much have to give your identity, b/c withholding will just heighten the possibility of being arrested. If you don't think there is reasonable suspicion you have the right to say no, but be aware of the potential consequences. On the other hand, if you’re on probation or parole, in most states revealing your identity will alert them to this and then they will usually have the right to conduct a legal search without probable cause. At this point, you need to exercise your right to keep your mouth shut (remain silent :~)and invoke your right to counsel.

Remember that the officer’s decision to detain you will not always hold up in court. Reasonable suspicion is a vague legal standard, somewhere less that probable cause but loosely defined. So if you’re searched or arrested following an officer’s ID request, you may have a defense that there was not reasonable suspicion; hence, everything to follow is fruit of the so-called poisonous tree.

Lastly, if the police reasonably suspect that you're armed and dangerous, they may conduct a "stop and frisk", which is a quick pat-down of the person’s outer clothing. They may not reach into your pocket if they don't feel a weapon. That is not to say they won't or don't, but they are not legally allowed to do so.

Comment: What is the difference in the US between "being detained" and "being arrested"?  I ask because England and Wales law has no such distinction; if you are not free to go, you are under arrest (even if the office hasn't formally announced that).  This is important for the visa waiver scheme where you are asked "have you ever been arrested?".  (And if I should ask this as a separate question, please say so.)

Comment: In the US, you can be detained by being put in the police car while a probable cause search is conducted, police can detain Without arrest for up to 48 hours if their is PC of a crime to give them time to investigate/question a suspect ( if they don't invoke counsel... If they do then they can hold but not question).

Comment: Detainment requires Miranda but Miranda and detainer doesn't necessarily mean one's been arrested.

Comment: I don't know much about US criminal law either, but there seems to be some [good discussion of this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-arrest-and-detention). It looks like 'arresting' a suspect might require the police to have 'probable cause' rather than 'reasonable suspicion.' Alternatively, it is suggested that you're only arrested when you are charged with a crime.

Comment: Reasonable suspicion for stop and frisk, or mv stop search of passenger cabin-PC  otherwise. Reasonable suspicion is the standard when the evidence will disappear i.e. in a car, or on foot, if there is a reasonable cause to believe a crime is taking place… And the time taken to get a warrant would likely mean the loss of all tangible evidence; but there are limitations. They cannot go be a cursory pat down ( although they often will search inside exterior pocket).probable cause otherwise, unless there are exiting. See "automobile exception", " terry stop", "stop and frisk".

Comment: Passenger cabin does not include the trunk or the glove box or in a center console, unless  probable cause arises

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I assume your Q refers to  "2) they see something illegal during the stop - like a weapon or a drug baggie - in plain view". While some states do allow the transport of weapons, they generally must not be loaded, be (for handguns) in a gun case, and typically the case must be locked. If police officer sees a weapon in plain view, used its presence does not comport with the law of that state, that is probable cause for a search.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov if you own a gun or travel with a weapon, or even if you're just interested in the law on these issues the NRA has a decent (albeit somewhat slanted) article that broadly covers the issue. https://www.nraila.org/articles/20150101/guide-to-the-interstate-transportation

Comment: @gracey209, Your link is down.

Comment: @Pacerier are you referring to the nraila.org link?  It works for me.

Comment: @phoog, Got it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20180321105149/https://www.nraila.org/articles/20150101/guide-to-the-interstate-transportation

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov:  It really depends on the state.  If you are a legal owner, you should make sure you know about your state's laws and any state you plan to be driving through.  No matter what, it is best to declare that there is a firearm in the vehicle, where it specifically is, and wait for the officer to instruct you.  Keep your hands on the wheel at all times or in the officers view and only make slow movements when asked to get anything from the officer.  Declaring what your intention is will help matters, especially if you are repeating his orders.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov:  Never point the muzzle at the officer, even if the fire arm is not loaded.  If the officer asks to handle the weapon, hand it to him grip first with the muzzle facing away from him and not pointed at anything you do not want to injure (good advice for any weapon or any potential weapon such as knives or screwdrivers no matter who you are handing it too).  If the officer wishes to return it too you, it is polite to hand it to you grip first, but it is safe to hand it to you muzzle first.  Do not be offended if he does the latter.

Comment: As a general rule, even if you have nothing to hide, refuse any search that is not warrented.  There is also something called Furrtive movements, which is when a cop, with lights on, sees you make unusual movements before he approaches you.  Keep your hands on the wheel and roll down the window.  If the cop conducts an unreasonable search of your vehicle do not resist... it raises tensions and the cop is definitely more scared of you than you are of him.  You can always call a lawyer and sue for damages.  But only if you are alive.

Comment: @hszmv:  Telling the officer that a gun was in the car turned out really badly for the late Philandro Castile.

Comment: @DavidThornley:  My understanding was that he made a sudden movement without informing the officer of his intent and the officer was jumpy.  It's been a while since I read the details though.

Comment: It is reasonable for a person with nothing to hide to object to a search because such a search is a waste of public resources (namely, the policeman's time).

Answer (score -2):

You will need to know that statutes and your citizenship status.  If there is a statute which requires you to do that thing, or a statute which requires you to do that thing when asked, and if you are also required to follow statutes, then you will have to do it.  That usually includes stating what you are called, or, if you have one, a name, when asked but not in every state - in some state you are not required to give a name or totally police what you are called when asked.  Aside from that one thing, anything else an offficer asks you to do is a request.  You can choose to do so or not do so.  However, there are some times when it is always a good idea to do so.  For example, if he says "get out of the street" or "stop yelling "Go Yankees!" ever time someone walks by", he may decide to arrest you for "disturbing the peace" or "disorderly conduct" if you don't.  However, if he asks you to turn in a circle and is not arresting you, tells you to give him your phone, tells you to sit down or stand up, or anything else that is not related to any statute, then you are not required to do so.