# Is illegal for a civilian to shine a light into police officer's car?

Tags: united-states, canada, police

Police officers often shine a light into your car or even your eyes. I find this very annoying. Their reasons of using such light is to "check if there is a hazard or any other safety issues in your car". I did some research and in general, there is no relevant clause prohibiting the usage a flashlight this way.

My question is, in US and Canada, is it illegal for a citizen do the **exactly same thing** to a police officer: shine a light back at them out of your car or shine a light into their car? The reason is simple: before the officer show the police ID I cannot be sure that it is actually the real police that has been stalking me. I have to use a flashlight to examine **if there is any hazard associated**. The reason is safety and self-protection.

Comment: I would have thought a more relevant question would be if it was legal to shine a light back at them out of your car

Comment: @User65535 Yes you are right, they are very similar things. I'll add it for sure.

Comment: On a practical level, reaching into a pocket or glove compartment to draw a metal object while dealing with US police is a *very* bad idea.

Comment: Do you not think it reasonable for the police to use a flashlight to evaluate the conditions inside the car?  If they are shining it in your face excessively, that's another matter, and you can ask them to stop and, if they don't, close your eyes.

Comment: ***"I would like to get shot. Is this a good way to go about it?"***

Comment: So, just trying to understand: You find encounters with the police annoying/unpleasant, and the remedy you propose is to deliberately antagonize the police officers? Regardless of legality, this is staggeringly foolish.

Comment: @RyanJensen Not deliberately antagonize them, but just copying what they are doing.

Comment: @dodo You and I both know that you only want to copy them because you think it will bother them.

Comment: It's all about context. If the patrol car is upside down in a ditch and you are trying to see if anyone is hurt in the dark, it is in all likelihood fine. In other contexts, not so much.

Comment: @ohwilleke If a patrol car is upside down in a ditch I'm going to point and laugh.

Comment: @RyanJensen So you are claiming that a police who is shining the light at you is deliberately antagonize you and bother you?

Comment: @RyanJensen I explicitly and clearly state that the reason is to examine any possible hazards in the night.

Answer (score 7):

### The police will order you to stop and then you have to obey.

The moment you annoy the police in a way that is hindering their work (such as blinding them with a flashlight), they can demand you to stop. if you don't comply, then you are committing a misdemeanor. For example, Virginia calls this ["refusal to aid [an] officer in execution of his office"](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/18.2-463/) and it is worded so widely, that the officer asking you to shut up and you don't, then you are guilty. If the order is in any way justifiable, then you not following the order is... well, criminal.

Plus, if you did not comply and they pulled out their handcuffs and you *still* don't comply with their demand, you are now resisting arrest, which at least in Virginia is again, [a misdemeanor.](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter10/section18.2-460/#)

Comment: jesus. Who wrote these laws? Cops can and will abuse them

Comment: The law is specifically limited to "in the execution of his office in a criminal case, (2) in the preservation of the peace, (3) in the apprehending or securing of any person for a breach of the peace, or (4) in any case of escape or rescue". They cannot legally order you to "shut up".

Comment: @user6726 'They cannot legally order you to "shut up"' [This case and answer seems to disagree](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36024/do-you-have-to-follow-all-the-orders-a-police-officer-gives)

Comment: Did you find some evidence that the defendant was convicted for not shutting up? We know that police give unlawful orders: being convicted is the litmus test for legality.

Comment: @user6726 when they are doing policework, they can demand you to shut up so they can work.

Comment: @SamB "jesus. Who wrote these laws? Cops can and will abuse them": where have you been for the last 3<backspace>50<backspace><backspace>150 years?  People abuse power.  The law has to provide police with power.  It therefore provides mechanisms to counter abuses of power by the police, but these mechanisms are imperfect.

Comment: @SamB the laws were written by the institutions that hire the police officers. But for most democratic countries, and as long as police officers stick to the laws, it is not that bad. Of course, the historical alternative would be going "classical style", in which the armed guards of the powerful were not bothered by those pesky "laws" as long as they did their masters'biding, and the common people could not vote who the powerful were.